# How to Scale-down one side of object - Blender 3.6.1

Tags: edit-mode

Attempting to scale down this one side of object to match the reference element on the left. I am in Blender 3.6.1, please provide detailed instruction, or reference documentation/video to how this can be accomplished. I have tried selecting in Edit Mode, using "S" scale, with "Z" axis to scale down, however object scales to middle pulling bottom of object up.

Recorded Video Explainer: https://youtu.be/O-Ni-MqCVzs

[image: Example of Object to Scale]

Comment: Select the top face of your object and then move it down using G Z?

Comment: And enable the Snap to Vertex option in order to snap to the other wall

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Scaling will move all elements towards/away from (scale below/above 1) the *Pivot Point*.

The *Pivot Point* is by default the *Median* (average) point. But you want to "scale down", therefore change the pivot point to be "down". You can achieve that by positioning your 3D cursor, either "by hand", using <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd>$\color{#888}{█0}\color{green}{█}$ *right mouse button*, or using <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> and one of the options, e.g. *Cursor to World Origin* or *Cursor to Selected*. Then if you also set the pivot point to the 3D Cursor (<kbd>.</kbd> key for menu), the scaling will work as you intend:

[image]

However, as pointed out by J.Eason and moonboots in comments, in your particular case it may be easier to just move the top using <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> keys… Then you can snap to the other object, and if there's more than just the top vertices to be moved, you can use <kbd>O</kbd> proportional editing.

Comment: Thank you - much closer with your help, J.Eason and moonboots help. I tried a variety of different tactics, I was able to set Origin/Pivot point + Select Sides of Object, but it warped other object elements in process - video of progress: https://youtu.be/F52VM1sOHqY

Comment: @NathanMallamace 0:31 is not the same as pressing the DOT key to change the transform pivot, in the graphic interface it's here: https://i.imgur.com/u3LeStc.png . Your movement (G key) doesn't quite work, because you have 'doubles' (multiply vertices in the same spots, and you don't select all of them), easiest fix: A, M, B keys in that order. The problem in 3:30 is caused by the vertex marked with red arrow defining the shape of the face marked green https://i.imgur.com/0wJsCix.png

Comment: @NathanMallamace I'd strongly suggest that you do one of the hundreds of free hard surface modelling courses online to get some practice. The comment from Marcus saying that you have double-vertices on your object shows that the basic topology of your model was wrong and that can cause all sorts of problems as you've found! For instance, you wouldn't usually model a simple L-shaped object using an angled edge at the corner.

Comment: Thank you - Markus, John & Moonboots. Video showing how I accomplished this - https://youtu.be/GwGFCUxcMp8